# how to create live trace search field in java

Tags: java, database, eclipse, search, netbeans

I want to create a live trace search field like google search, for my java desktop application using mysql or sql server data base. I have no idea how to do it. please send me a web link or some stuff to learn about it. I googled but directly not found anything

Comment: Take a look at [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widely accepted way of searching files in desktops or a large number of file in a given hardware is using lucene - refer - http://lucene.apache.org/core/
,  http://www.lucenetutorial.com/